# Website is very slow

Tags: php, server

I have a website,before is everything was good,fast,without problems. <--In this time I used,one free server.
Now the problem is I bought a server good,quailty,just is very very slow.

Whats wrong? My idea is something with session,beacuse I get this error:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   /home/origomal/public_html/index.php:8) in
>   /home/origomal/public_html/index.php on line 18

On the free server I didn't get this error.

The url:[origomalta.com](http://origomalta.com)

PS:Every loop is very small,I need to wait for loop more than 3minits(120row)

Comment: What happens on line 8 in `/home/origomal/public_html/index.php`?

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 1):

Not likely to be the cause of slow speed, but this happens because output buffering is not enabled by default on your new host. You can enable it by setting the `output_buffering` runtime configuration option to `On` in a local `php.ini` or `.htaccess` file. You can also resolve it directly from your code by adding `ob_start()` at the beginning of your PHP file(s).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, helped a little bit,but I deleted this code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Now,is good :)

Comment: What you did with this was only to hide the error message. You should really resolve the errors instead of hiding them. See my previous answer.

Comment: Hey,I saw,and i tried,but nothing,when i delete this code,after its start to work normaly!